# Cheese wont die

Tags: command-line, bash, webcam, kill, cheese

Im trying to figure out a problem Im having with a motion server, and a given CCD camera, on `/dev/video0`
So, I had been viewing the camera stream using cheese. But now cheese has hung up, and wont die.

```
$ ps aux | grep cheese
jay      22959  0.3  0.6 557144 56288 pts/0    D+   08:47   0:00 cheese /dev/video0
jay      22981  0.0  0.0  15184  2196 pts/2    S+   08:49   0:00 grep --color=auto cheese
$ pkill -9 cheese
$ sudo pkill -9 cheese
[sudo] password for jay: 
$ ps aux | grep cheese
jay      22959  0.2  0.6 557144 56288 pts/0    D+   08:47   0:00 cheese /dev/video0
jay      22986  0.0  0.0  15184  2272 pts/2    S+   08:50   0:00 grep --color=auto cheese
$ sudo kill -9 22959
$ ps aux | grep cheese
jay      22959  0.1  0.6 557144 56288 pts/0    D+   08:47   0:00 cheese /dev/video0
jay      22990  0.0  0.0  15184  2288 pts/2    S+   08:50   0:00 grep --color=auto cheese
```

short of rebooting, what can i do to kill cheese? sudo kill -9 usually works.